# Please help me Optimize MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have Query below, the query return correct result, but when there more then 10000 row in table **cslogcurve_datanode**, My Query take long time effort, and i want to ask how to optimize or the best sintax for my query and must return same result with my query below

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-1' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R1,
    (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-10' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R2
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-11' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R3,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-12' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R4,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-13' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R5,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-14' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R6,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-15' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R7,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-16' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R8,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-17' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R9,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-18' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R10
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-19' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R11,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-2' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R12,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-20' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R13,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-21' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R14,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-3' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R15,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-4' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R16,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-5' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R17,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-6' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R18,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-7' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R19,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-8' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R20,
     (SELECT dataNode FROM cslogcurve_datanode s1 WHERE logCurveInfoUID = 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-9' AND s1.baseNodeDouble = t.baseNodeDouble) AS R21 
  FROM cslogcurve_datanode t ORDER BY R1 ASC
```

Comment: Use [`IN`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

Comment: Didn't the given answer help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`IN`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) clause instead.
Syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <COLUMN> 
FROM <TABLE> 
WHERE <COLUMN> IN (<VALUE1>,<VALUE2>,...) 
ORDER BY <COLUMN>;
```

So your query should be like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dataNode 
FROM cslogcurve_datanode 
WHERE logCurveInfoUID IN ('W-12B-01f34a-lci-1', 'W-12B-01f34a-lci-10'
                         ,'W-12B-01f34a-lci-11','W-12B-01f34a-lci-12'
                         ,'W-12B-01f34a-lci-13',....)
ORDER BY dataNode ASC;
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, but the result is a series of rows, not a pile of columns with assigned names.